# What will be the distance travelled by Bwhen A and C meet for the first time after 10:05Am given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

It was asked in my exams.

MyApproach:

time taken for A and C to meet is t=2150/15=143.33sec=2min 38sec

We cannot take this time since we have to calculate their first meeting after 10:05

Therefore,I get now

t=4300/15=286.66=4 min 76 sec

Therefore,the time is 7min 84sec for first meeting after 10:05.

$7$ . $60$+ $84$sec=504sec

=>Distance travelled by B=$504$ . $8$=$4032$m

But the Ans given is 3440

> IS my approach right towards the  problem?Please correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your conversion in min.sec

143,33sec=2min 23,3sec

286.66sec = 4min 46,6sec

the time for the meeting is 6.70 =7.10min=430sec

distance travelled by B=430*8=3440

Comment: I am getting $143.33$/$60$=$2min 38?

Comment: 2.38min not 2min38sec ! 1min=60sec

Comment: 0.388833/100*60=0.2333 ->23.33sec

Comment: $0.388833$/$100$*$60$=$0.0000648055$?

Comment: (0.388833/100)*60=0.23